# Prove the formula of combination number

Tags: real-analysis, summation, combinations

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n\\
 k\\
\end{array} \right) \frac{\left( -1 \right) ^k}{x+k}=\frac{n!}{x\left( x+1 \right) \cdots \left( x+n \right)}}
\\
$$
I recently read an article and found this formula above. I tried to prove it, but only proved the following result. I don't know how to prove this more general combinatorial equation.
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n\\
 k\\
\end{array} \right) \frac{\left( -1 \right) ^k}{m+k+1}=\int_0^1{\sum_{k=0}^n{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n\\
 k\\
\end{array} \right) \left( -1 \right) ^kx^{m+k}\text{d}x}=\int_0^1{x^m\left( 1-x \right) ^n}\text{d}x}=\frac{m!n!}{\left( m+n+1 \right) !}}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S_{n,x}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k}\frac{(-1)^k}{x+k}= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \int_{0}^{1} {n \choose k}(-1)^k t^{x+k-1} dt=\int_{0}^{1} t^{x-1}(1-t)^n dt~~~~(1)$$
$$S_{n,x}= \frac{\Gamma(x) \Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+x+1)}~~~~~~~(2)$$ If $x$ is an integer, then
$$S_{n.x}=\frac{(x-1)!~ n!}{(x+n)!}=\frac{(x-1)!}{x(x+1))(x+2)...(x+n)}~~~~(3)$$

Here we have use $\beta$ function

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Note: OP needs to correct the result.

Comment: If x is not an integer, then（n+x）！. How should it be defined

Comment: Then youw will have to work with (2), see my edited version.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I just went back to the definition of Euler integral. Now I understand。

Comment: You are welcome, you may accept one answer now.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**:consider by binomial theorem$$x^m{(1-x)}^n=\binom{n}{0}x^m-\binom{n}{1}x^{m+1}+\binom{n}{2}x^{m+2}..$$

Now integrate with limits $0$ to $1$

For integration part see [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

Comment: I used beta function to prove the second combinational number formula, but the denominator of the left part of the first equation has x, I do not know how to use beta function to prove

Comment: @WSSF please be specific when you say first equation which do you mean?

Comment: Ok, so that's the first formula I put in.

Answer (score 0):

By partial fractions, we know
$$\frac{n!}{x(x+1) \cdots (x+n)} = \frac{a_0}{x} + \frac{a_1}{x+1} + \dots + \frac{a_n}{x+n}$$
for some set of numbers $a_0, a_1, \dots , a_n$. To find $a_k$ we multiply both sides of the equation by $x+k$ and then set $x=-k$ in the resulting equation.  The result is
$$a_k = (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}$$